# lua uart.alt(1) how to make it work

Tags: lua, uart, esp8266

I was hoping to use the alt uart on esp8266 and tried the following:

```
uart.alt(1)
uart.setup(0, 19200, 8, uart.PARITY_NONE, uart.STOPBITS_1, 0)
```

unfortunately, it give me an error "attempt to call field 'alt' (a nil value)".  Why?  I thought that I was setting uart to alt(1) in this case.  Not sure why it's nil value.  Any comments?

Answer (score 2):

> "attempt to call field 'alt' (a nil value)"

This error indicates that `uart` is a *table*, but that the *field* `alt` is `nil`. Since you cannot call `nil` like a function you get this error. The error has nothing to do with the *argument* you are providing.

`uart.alt` *should* be available by default in a NodeMCU environment, as indicated by both the [documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/uart/#uartalt) and [implementation](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/uart.c).

Have you done anything earlier in your program, or firmware compilation, that would result in the `alt` field becoming `nil`?

Comment: Thank for you comment, but in my case, I am testing it with just the above two lines so uart was not used earlier.  I suspect that the uart.alt is not available on ESP8266, or perhaps the version I have is not available? (ESP8266-12e).  If anyone got uart.alt working on ESP8266, I would be glad to hear about it.

Comment: @Terrapin Which version of the NodeMCU firmware is loaded on your chip? Who makes your board?

Comment: My NodeMCU was custom built at https://nodemcu-build.com/.  Was given the file to download nodemcu-master-9-modules-2016-06-18-22-20-43-float.bin.  No idea version number, but uart was supposed to be part of it.

Comment: Wait, the node.info() gives 0 9 5 so I guess it's 0.95; the hardware is ESP8266-12E LoLin.

Answer (score 0):

It may be UART module is missing somehow though it's ON by default in https://nodemcu-build.com/

When you connect to your board from ESPlorer at startup, you should see some initial info about the firmware and it's modules.
Like:

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
branch: master
commit: b96e31477ca1e207aa1c0cdc334539b1f7d3a7f0
SSL: true
modules: adc,bit,bme280,cjson,crypto,encoder,file,gpio,http,i2c,mdns,mqtt,net,node,pwm,sntp,spi,tmr,uart,websocket,wifi,ws2812,tls
```

Do you see UART in your startup console?